# Retain PHP form information across pages

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I am trying to solve this problem:

Basically, a user fills in a HTML form then submits it. They are then redirected to another page where they fill in another form. Both forms are finally captured by PHP using `$_POST`. How is it possible to retain the information from the first form across the second form so both are submitted?

Comment: save the form data you want to keep in the session

Comment: Either: store the form values from the first form in `$_SESSION`, and retrieve them after the second form is submitted, or add the first form values to the second form as hidden `<INPUT>`, and retrieve all the values from the `$_POST` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
<input type="hidden" name="something" value="<?php echo "{$_POST['fromoldpage']}";?>"/>
```

Comment: It works! Someone else wrote something similar but this is the only complete answer so I'll accept it in 6 minutes...

Comment: I woudn't do it this way, personally. In general, when you do a post operation, if there were no validation errors, it is advisable to _redirect_ immediately afterwards. This means that the new page can be refreshed without doing the POST again (useful if you are writing to a database and don't want that operation duplicated) and it solves some problems with browser back buttons too.

Answer (score 2):

Echo the fields from the first form into hidden fields on the second:

<input type='hidden' name='name' value='value'>